# Symfony best practices. Should queries be in repositories or services?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a question about best practices in Symfony 2. Sorry if it's a bit vague and subjective. I guess I can sum up my question as:

"Are repositories always the right place for queries?".

Right now I'm putting most of my doctrine queries in entity repositories. Most of my controller actions do typical things like query for an entity or collection of entities, throw an exception or redirect depending on the outcome of that, otherwise update one or more entities. Most actions are more complex than can be done efficiently with the standard ->find, ->findBy etc queries. Most require joins. When a query involves multiple entities, sometimes I'm not sure which repository it should even go in. I guess there is the root entity of the query but ... sometimes data from the joined entities are more important and relevant so it feels wrong to put it in the root entity's repository.

That's working okay but I tend to end up with lots of almost the same but slightly different queries in my repositories. Coming up with names and keeping track of exactly what each one does can get confusing and tedious. Most of these queries are used by only one or two (often seldom used) controller actions in the same controller. I feel like I'm cluttering my repositories with too much specialized, seldom used stuff.

It seems like all but the most simple actions should be encapsulated in an object or service. So, I've started doing a lot of my queries directly in the service rather than a repository. It's easy to look at the action all in one place.  Is this an okay practice?

Comment: the controller should be a really thin layer between the application world and the http world and I recommend always to put the queries in repositories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your queries should be kept in your entity **repositories** and not in your controllers to be able to **re-use** them easily.

That's what the repositories are for actually. Providing a re-usable location for the database queries.

There are however some situations where keeping all your queries in the repository can be improved ... especially when it comes to filtering where quickly a lot of queries may be needed.

Benjamin Eberlei ( creator of Doctrine ) considers 5 public methods in a class to be okay and 10 to be fairly large. He has recently published an interesting article called "[On Taming Repository Classes in Doctrine](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html)" about this on his blog.

I partly do like the filterable repository trait solution by KnpLabs in their [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#filterable) aswell.

Traits make testing harder but you can have a cleaner and easier to maintain **repository** ... *where you should keep your queries*.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are both interesting. I wasn't going to put queries in my controllers. I'm just looking for a way to avoid bloating my repositories with lots of similar but not quite the same queries with similar but not quite the same names.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something inbetween.

Define a service:

```
blog.post_manager:
    class: Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Manager\PostManager
    arguments:
        em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        class: Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
```

Then create the Manager class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostManager
{
    protected $em;

    protected $repo;

    protected $class;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $class) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->repo = $em->getRepository($class);
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->repo->findById($id);
    }
}
```

This way, you can still leave queries where they belong, in repositories, while allowing code re-use through the manager service which can be used like this in any controller:

```
$this->container->get('blog.post_manager')->get(1);
```

Since the service takes care of injecting the class and entity manager to the Manager class, this also keeps the controller thinner and better abstracts it away from the model.

Comment: +1 manager classes are a good tip though the real question was where to keep his queries - which should almost always be the repository. A manager class provides the advantage of abstracting different ways to access your database. you can have one manager class using an entity repository , another using document repository another using a completely different storage backend. as long as they all implement the same interface you can exchange them in your controller. That's how i.e. FOSUserBundle handles doctrine orm, odm and propel :)

Comment: "This way, you can still leave queries where they belong, in repositories, [...]"

Comment: I usually directly inject the repository using a service factory into my manager classes ... even cleaner :-)

Comment: That works too, there are a few cases where it's useful to have the class handy, but either way works.

Comment: @nifr a bit old answer, but you never should inject the repository in your entity.

Comment: @nifr sorry, misreading. You mentioned injecting the repository into manager class (+1, doing the same stuff, my manager classes look like your example to be honest), not the entity itself. Sorry for being blind jerk.

Comment: Hehe I was just re-reading the answers when I saw your comment ... and asked myself if and where I might have instructed to do that :) Manager classes are definitely a good way to glue your application-logic and data-storage together.

Comment: @nifr Definitely agree. Once again, sorry for messing up. I will practice reading, I promise :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why name such a service `PostManager`? IMO, Such a generic suffix should be avoided

Comment: While things may have changed, that was the convention at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The repository responsibility is to provide a non-technical interface to your domain objects.
The actual query implementation *can* stay in the repository, but is better to encapsulate it in a class that has the single responsibility to build the query.
Controllers (or application services) *shouldn't* contain the implementation detail of the query, they should just call the repository (as if it was a collection) or a query factory (if you want to handle the querying or the result yourself).
Ideally controllers should have little code and just call to "SRPecialized" services.

---

---

*You can try to implement this simple architectural option. It fits Doctrine or whatever other ORM library. It honours separation of concerns, as intended in [Martin Fowler's PoEAA book](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)*, providing a layer for abstraction of persistence details and composition.

---

## Why a repository?

Repositories responsibility is to handle a collection, so actual operational code should go there. The queries should be collected/composed/generated somewhere else, like in a factory class (as mentioned previously). This allows to switch the underlying persistence layer implementation without touching the part of domain/application logic that is held inside Repositories.

You can derive from this, depending on your application, but when queries start to be dynamic, with several parameters, or simply too long, I tend to abstract each query in its own class, and just call them from the repository.

## Query construction

Each query can have a *static constructor* that is called by the repository. For more complex cases alternative I define a simple `QueryFactory` as entrypoint for the available custom queries; this will allow a more flexible configuration of dependencies, thanks to Symfony DI.

---

## An example of implementation

```
namespace App\Repository;

// use statements

class ArticleRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getPublished()
    {
        $query = App\Query\Article::getPublished(\DateTimeImmutable $after = null);
        $query_iterator = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query);
        
        // ... run query ...
    }
}
```

so you can have custom methods for specific variations of the query (e.g. getPublished, getUnpublished, getNewArticles, or whatever else).

```
namespace App\Query;

// use statements

final class Articles
{
    public static function getPublished(\DateTimeImmutable $after = null)
    {
        return new self(Article::PUBLISHED_STATE, $this->sqlFormat($after));
    }

    public function __constructor(string $status, \DateTimeImmutable $date_filter = null) {
        
        // ... you own complex query logic ...
    }
}

// ...

$published_query = Articles::getPublished();

// ...
```

- The maintenance becomes slightly annoying because of proxying through the static constructors and having one more file to go through when tracing back a bug on the stack. Although it scales up better.
- in general it gives a good & flexible organization in project that spawn many complex or non-standard queries.
- in my opinion the *Repository Pattern* is supposed to be agnostic about implementation details at persistence level (what database adapter is used under the hood: SQL? NoSQL?).
- composition, and abstraction of parts that are common for queries from different repository, are more easily achievable.